# Analytics API integration rails failing on heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, google-analytics, production

I am currently developing a ruby on rails application which includes the gattica gem to fetch Google Analytics data. When I fetch my data:
https://github.com/activenetwork/gattica

```
gs = Gattica.new({:email => 'johndoe@google.com', :password => 'password', :profile_id => 123456})
results = gs.get({ :start_date => '2008-01-01', 
                   :end_date => '2008-02-01', 
                   :dimensions => 'browser', 
                   :metrics => 'pageviews', 
                   :sort => '-pageviews'})
```

on development I will simply receive a response which I can parse to my application.

However on production the page returns a 500 error and in my Gmail inbox I receive a message about a suspicious login being caught.

Is there any way I can fix this issue?

PS: my application is hosted on Heroku.

With kind regards,
Dennis

Comment: I think you should read logs. 500 almost always means that your app crashed, so you should find why

Comment: The 500 response is the response from the google API which trigger an exception in my application. However this cannot be bypassed from the application itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the 500 error because Google is blocking your heroku ip from accessing your account. They aren't sure it's you.

You need to change your activity settings to authorize that ip/domain.

Read this: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1144110?hl=en&ref_topic=2401957

Also, its a good idea to read your logs when debugging these kinds of errors.   `Rails.logger.debug results`  could shed some light.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, after going through: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha my account now accepts the requests and handles them properly!